# How to commit a project to SVN which has absolute paths from cmake build?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, cmake, commit

I used this [cmakelists.txt](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds-cxx/blob/master/examples/helloworld/CMakeLists.txt) file with CMake build and created VS solution

created project's ALL_BUILD.vcxproj contains absolute paths.

**I need to commit the project to SVN so that other developers can checkout my committed project and rebuild it in their PCs.... but since CMake has put an absolute path on custom rules/ linking... others cannot use the committed project as it is...**

**during sln build of checkout files, visual studio looking for absolute paths in my PC...**

What is the best way to handle committing this type of project to SVN?

should I commit only the source files?

Source files mean userdds.h , userdds.cpp etc, cmakelists.txt, and DDS includes/libs/dlls without .sln and .vcproject plus any generated files

Comment: You commit the source code and the `CMakeLists.txt` files (as well as any other files used as input in the cmake configurations); this list is not necessarily complete, since there may be other files such as toolchain files that should be included; as a general rule of thumb onlu files you added, not those that cmake did add should become part of the repository. After getting these files other developers should use cmake to create their own project locally. build products including dlls should not be commited.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it sounds too similar to the one you recently asked.